# Index Match to Return Second To Last Non-Numerical Entry

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

My team has to fill in their schedules in google forms each week, and basically I'm trying to do it so if they select "Maintain," I can automatically pull their last/previously filled entry.

So far I've gotten this:
`=if(D23="Maintain",(INDEX('Form Responses'!$E$2:$R,MATCH($C23,'Form Responses'!$B$2:$B)-1)),(INDEX('Form Responses'!$E$2:$R,MAX(IF('Form Responses'!$B$2:$B=C23,ROW(C:C))))))`
but the "True" section isn't returning the right row (with or without the "-1").

The name "JC" is supposed to show the data from row32 in the responses sheet, and "NA" is supposed to return that of row40.

The "-1" is supposed to Index/Match the second-to-last entry with that specific name, but I can't tell if it's working correctly or not.

What am I doing wrong with the "True" portion?

Sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FeYzXH3spqKqZAZWpKO0PFMdYuTjrtDoZIxlW50B-ns/edit#gid=1728521224

Comment: Hi, can you visually clarify what is the expected output? Where would the desired formula be located, and what would it return?

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't clear!
In "Sheet6" cell E23 and across is supposed to be populated with data from row 32 of the "responses" sheet, and E25 is supposed to show that of row 40. 

If the team member selects "Maintain," then this "sheet6" will show the data from the second-to-last entry found in "responses," and if not, it'll just show the last entry (the "False" part of the formula - which is working correctly).

Comment: I can't se anythig in `what it's supposed to look like` ...

Comment: You'll have to scroll down to row23ish. I wanted to keep the rows the same so it was easier to identify.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation. How can you do with 2 consecutive days with 'maintain'?

Comment: There is another solution that saves you from duplicating all the data. You can use onFormSubmit(e) with a trigger so that all data is replaced with previous ones in case of 'Maintain'. Doing this will also take into account consecutive days with  maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in E3:R range and use in E3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(D3:D="Maintain", 
 VLOOKUP(C3:C, QUERY(SORT('Form Responses'!B2:R, ROW('Form Responses'!B2:B), 0), 
 "where not Col2 = 'Maintain' and Col1 is not null", 0), COLUMN(D:Q), 0),
 VLOOKUP(C3:C, SORT('Form Responses'!B2:R, ROW('Form Responses'!B2:B), 0), COLUMN(D:Q), 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, thank you so much! Would you also happen to know why my "true" part of the formula was giving me the wrong output?

Comment: @Beee didnt investigate it much coz this index/match design has its flaws. disadvantage of vlookup is that it will always bring up the first found result but with some additional sorting and querying we can flip and filter it in such way we want to get what we need

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that saves you from duplicating your database.

When a new response is submitted, if `Maintain` is specified, this function will retrieve the last response for the same `Name` and duplicate the data already entered. Doing this will allow you to maintain during for consecutive days.

```
// this function needs to be triggered
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  if (responses["Maintain/New"] == 'Maintain') {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[1] == responses["Name"]).sort(function (a, b) {
      return b[0] - a[0];
    });
    if (data.length > 1) {
      data = data.splice(1, 1).flat()
      data.splice(0, 3)
      sheet.getRange(row,4,1,data.length).setValues([data])
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need it to fit into the original table/rows as there will be responses added each week, with different members choosing to "maintain," so this isn't quite what I'm looking for. Thank you anyway!

Comment: ok I have updated my answser